# I can build a UITableView between two UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I created a standard UITableView, the selection of a cell must leave a subtable of detail between two tableviewCell. How can I do? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use insertRowsAtIndexPaths to insert a new row above/below the selected cell like this.

```
[tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationBottom];
```

and Customize the method as per your requirement.